# Session-cookie not set on the next request - Express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, express, cookies

I'm trying to set a cookie when logging in, but the cookie doesn't seem to follow to the next request. What am I doing wrong? (Sorry if nooby question, quite new to express).

The app.js

```
let express = require("express");
let session = require("express-session");
let bodyParser = require("body-parser");

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(session({
    secret: "secret",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: { secure: true }
}));
```

The router

```
router.route("/login")
    .get(function(request, response) {

        response.render("../views/partials/login");
    })

    .post(function(request, response) {

        let username = request.body.username;
        let password = request.body.password;

        User.findOne({user: username}, function(err, user) {
            if (err) {
                // Some error handling
            }

            // test password if matching
            if (user !== null) {
                user.comparePassword(password, function(err, match) {
                    if (err || !match) {
                        console.log("The user could not be found")
                    }

                    request.session.Auth = { username: username, password: password };
                    response.redirect("/home");
                    response.end();
                });
            } else {
                // some error handling
            }
        });

    });
```

Then when I do the next request on "/home", the session cookie holds no value about the user(**req.session.Auth returns undefined**)

```
router.route("/home")
    .get(restrict, function(req,res) {

console.log(req.session.Auth) // -> undefined
        res.render("../views/home")
    });
```

Maybe I'm doing this wrong, but I can't understand why the request.session doesn't hold the Auth-value. Can somebody please help?

P.S. I do not want to use any modules to handle authorization, like passport etc.

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is not going to work.

I really recommend you use `passport.js` for authentication. It's very simple, and takes away a lot of the work you're doing now. Accessing the request object in this post request does nothing.

Comment: Forgot to add that I do not want to do it with passport.js for learning-purposes :). But why isn't it working?

Comment: The request object has the data pertaining to the request that was made from the client. The only thing the client gets back is the response, the request doesn't go back to the client.

Comment: can you send the session-cookie as a response then?

Comment: Yes, and you should implement logic that checks that cookie for every subsequent request.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this way.

First enabled cookie session in express

```
app.use(express.cookieParser('S3CRE7'));
app.use(express.cookieSession({
    key: 'app.key',
    secret: 'app.secret'
}));
app.use(app.router);
```

after enabling cookie session, you can get/set what ever property to request.session.

I think rest of your logic is fine.

Comment: Doesn't work with express 4^, returns: Most middleware (like cookieParser) is no longer bundled with Express and must be installed separately. Please see https://github.com/senchalabs/connect#middleware.

Comment: So we can import that middleware into the project.

Answer (score 0):

Are you testing your app in HTTPS? If not, then you should initialize the express session without the `cookie: { secure: true }` property, as

```
app.use(session({
    secret: "secret",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}));
```

A secure cookie is a cookie that will only be sent when HTTPS is used.